# How can I change the Wireless Adapter Interface Name in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, udev

I've booted with the `net.ifnames=0` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` so
It does fix the name of the **internal** adapter

```
wlp2s0 >> wlan0
```

But I can't find a solution to my **external** adapter which is **AWUS036H**

when I run `iwconfig` I get

```
kira@dark:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlx983f9f25df10  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

This extra weird name `wlx983f9f25df10` is my problem;

or even `airmon-ng`

```
kira@dark:~$ sudo airmon-ng

PHY     Interface       Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlan0           iwlwifi     Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
phy1    wlx983f9f25df10 rt2800usb   Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070
```

I use my external card a lot in the terminal, I don't want to write this whole name or copy/paste it every time I want to call a command. Can't I just change it to a simpler name like `wlan1`?

On **Ubuntu 17.04**, I tried editing in `rules.d` and `udev` according to some answers but It
doesn't work and I may be editing *in a wrong way* cause I don't really know what to edit/remove or change there for this specific adapter, Thanks.

Comment: You need ``rules.d``, but what did you wrote there exactly? Read https://rundata.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/renaming-network-interfaces/ for example